# generate dynamic JSON with ASPX

Tags: asp.net, json

I want to create a webpage which display a list of message which is encapsulated in JSON (using JavaScript).
However, there is one sentence "Hello! You are the -th Visitor" at the beginning of this list is dynamic. How can I achieve that? I program in ASP .NET. Can C# eval a value in a JSON file? Do I have to ask ASP .NET to read one whole JSON file and generate a new JSON file just for this purpose?